# What should you do in this position?

Tags: analysis

I no longer have this game, although I do remember losing it. Here's the setup of the game, with White to move:

```
[fen "2b1kb1r/r5pp/8/p1pQBp2/qn1P1P2/6P1/4P2P/2R1KR2 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Who's on move??

Comment: You see that religious "Christian" at the bottom? His piece is glowing because it's his turn.

Comment: What happened to the picture?!?!

Comment: The picture was edited out. This diagram is the standard way of displaying chess positions on this exchange.

Comment: I don't see any "diagram". I see a piece of code: [fen "2b1kb1r/r5pp/8/p1pQBp2/qn1P1P2/6P1/4P2P/2R1KR2 w - - 0 1"]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Safari, iPod 4th generation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White can safely resign. He is down 2 pieces without compensation and Black has a passed pawn.

Now, Black's King is not secure, so if the White Q could get a check in, it is possible the Queen and Bishop could be a threat.  However, I see nothing here that makes me think White can get anything going.

So `Qc4` to keep the Queen close to the action while keeping an eye on `g8` to prevent castling. This pins the Knight on `b4` though I don't know that it matters much.

If White gets time, he could consider `Kf2`.  This will connect the White rooks in preparation for Rfd1, after which White shoves the d-pawn down Black's gullet.  If Black takes it, all the better.

But White really is doomed.

Comment: @warspyking more comments added.

Comment: White's queen is currently hanging on d5

Comment: @Cleveland yeah just saw that.

Comment: It doesn't really matter but Qa1+ is an improvement over Nxd5 after 1. Rc4

Comment: @Cleveland maybe I should delete this post, lol

Comment: Resign unless you are playing a real patzer and its blitz.